# Как скруглить углы без CSS3 с минимальным кодом, без больших нарезанных рисунков и кроссбраузерно?

Tags: html

Если вас не затруднит, пожалуйста помогите решить проблему.
Для скругления уголков квадратного рисунка без применения CSS3 и  употребления больших нарезанных рисунков, не нашла в интернете оптимального и кроссбраузерного решения(при разных разрешениях  экрана уголки рисунков(маленьких corner-ов) выходили за пределы бордера.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Варианта, подходящего под все условия — нет. Остаётся только:

а) делать углы изображениями, но при этом DOM-структура блока с заокруглёнными углами будет сравнительно большой.

б) все-таки использовать css3 - будет проще, но не кроссбраузерно.

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно но можно у рисунков поставить размер в %

Answer (score -5):

Посмотри тут

[Border-radius](http://border-radius.com/)

```
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
```